# typeerror: cannot destructure property 'user' of '(0 , react__webpack_imported_module_0__.usecontext)(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on this project and suddenly this error appeared in chrome's console.log `typeerror: cannot destructure property 'user' of '(0 , react__webpack_imported_module_0__.usecontext)(...)' as it is undefined.`and im a bit stuck on how to solve this. I double check everything and i didnt see what's the problem.

Here is my App.js

```
import AppNavBar from './components/AppNavBar'
import './App.css';
import  {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './pages/Home'
import Register from './pages/Register'
import Login from './pages/Login'
import Logout from './pages/Logout'
import Error from './pages/Error'
import {UserProvider} from './UserContext'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({
    id: null,
    isAdmin: null
  })
const unsetUser = () => {
  localStorage.clear()
  setUser({
    id:null,
    isAdmin: null
  })
}
useEffect(()=>{
  let token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
    // console.log(token)
    fetch('https://e-commerce-capstone-2.herokuapp.com/users/details',{
      headers:{
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }).then(res =>res.json()).then(convertedData =>{ 
      // console.log(convertedData)

      if (typeof convertedData._id !== "undefined") {
          setUser({
            id: convertedData._id,
            isAdmin: convertedData.isAdmin
          });
         // console.log(user)
    } else {
        setUser({
          id: null,
          isAdmin: null
        })
      }
    })
    
},[user])
  return (
   
    <Router>
    <AppNavBar/>
    <Routes>
    <Route path= '/' element={<Home/>} />
    <Route path= '/register' element={<Register/>} />
    <Route path= '/login' element={<Login/>} />
    <Route path= 'logout' element={<Logout/>}/>
     <Route path= '*' element={<Error/>} />
    }
    }
    </Routes>
    </Router>
    
  
   

  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Navbar component

```
import {useContext} from 'react'
import {Navbar, Nav, Container,Image,NavDropdown} from 'react-bootstrap'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import UserContext from '../UserContext'

function AppNavBar(){
    const {user} = useContext(UserContext)
    return(
            <Navbar className='Navbar fs-1' expand='lg' variant='light'>
            <Container>
            <Navbar.Brand><Image className='backgroundlogo ml-auto' src='logo.png' fluid style={{height:'200px',width:'200px'}}/></Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls = "responsive-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse >
            
            <Nav className='ml-auto'>
            <Link to ='/' className='nav-link'>Home</Link>
            {user.id !== null ?
                <Link to ='/logout' className='nav-link'>Logout</Link>
                :
            
                <>
                <Link to ='/login' className='nav-link'>Login</Link>
                <Link to ='/register' className='nav-link'>Register</Link>
                </>
                }
                
            <NavDropdown  title = 'Products' className='NavDropdown'>
                        
                <NavDropdown.Item>
                <Link  to ='/products' className='nav-link'>Overview</Link>
                </NavDropdown.Item>                     
                <NavDropdown.Item>
                <Link  to ='/products/add' className='nav-link'>Add Products</Link>
                </NavDropdown.Item> 
                <NavDropdown.Item>
                <Link  to ='/products/update' className='nav-link'>Update Products</Link>
                </NavDropdown.Item>
                

            </NavDropdown>
                <Link to ='/products/addtocart' className='nav-link'>Buy Now</Link>
            </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>              
            </Container>

            </Navbar>
        )
}
export default AppNavBar;
```

for more info, here is the gitlab link of the project:
https://gitlab.com/zekevergara/projects/e-commerce/e-commerce

Answer (score 0):

I see whats my mistake here. While coding my navbar, I forgot to add UserProvider so i put `<UserProvider value ={{user, setUser ,unsetUser}}>` before  and `</UserProvider>` after `</Router>` and it works!